# how to make like this white boostrap

Tags: html, css

How to make like this picture (which is in red circle)

[image]

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <img class="img-responsive user-photo" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png">
  </div>
  <!-- /thumbnail -->
</div>
<!-- /col-sm-1 -->
<div class="col-sm-10">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <strong>myusername</strong> <small><span class="text-muted">commented 5 days ago</span></small>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body"> Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content
    </div>
    <!-- /panel-body -->
  </div>
  <!-- /panel panel-default -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the jsfiddle link.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers this should help you like this.as you are using bootstrap.

Comment: check answer may be it's help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use below css part

Working fiddle

**[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0zvfvm6q/38/)**

**css**

```
.panel-heading.angle {
  position:relative;
}
.panel-heading.angle:after {
  content:'';
  border-top:10px solid transparent;
  border-right:10px solid #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
  border-left:10px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  left:-20px;
  top:12px;
}
.panel-heading.angle:before {
  content:'';
  border-top:11px solid transparent;
  border-right:11px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom:11px solid transparent;
  border-left:11px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  left:-22px;
  top:11px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-heading angle">
  <strong>myusername</strong> <small><span class="text-muted">commented 5 days ago</span></small>
</div>
```

Add `angle` class like above html part

Answer (score 0):

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wbb7zen/).

You can get this to work by working on border's of the div element.

```
.arrow-up {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;

  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;

  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.arrow-right {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 60px solid transparent;

  border-left: 60px solid green;
}

.arrow-left {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 

  border-right:10px solid blue; 
}
```

Reference : http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Reference : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `after` and `before` in css. Please check this in full view [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Gt25L/1231/)

```css
.panel-default:before {
    border-right: 10px solid #ddd;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
.panel-default:after, .panel-default:before {
    color: transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    content: "";
    left: -5px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><div class="col-sm-2">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive user-photo" src="https://ssl.gstatic.com/accounts/ui/avatar_2x.png">
                        </div><!-- /thumbnail -->
                    </div><!-- /col-sm-1 -->
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <strong>myusername</strong> <small><span class="text-muted">commented 5 days ago</span></small>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body"> Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content Panel content
                            </div><!-- /panel-body -->
                        </div><!-- /panel panel-default -->
                    </div>
```